# how to pass array in jquery to a web service

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

This is my jquery

```
 var selectedCampaigns = $("#campaignDiv input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    console.log(selectedCampaigns);

$.getJSON(webServiceUrl,
      { fromDate: valFrom, toDate: valTo, campaigns: selectedCampaigns })
       .done(function (result) {
```

This is the request :

```
Request URL:http://localhost:4025/vmp_webservice.asmx/LoadService2Daily?fromDate=2014-05-26+00%3A00%3A00&toDate=2014-05-26+23%3A59%3A01&campaigns%5B%5D=direct&campaigns%5B%5D=Sales
```

This is the response (500 internal error):

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.UrlParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

The web service is not envoke at all because I put breakpoints in the first line but the break point is not fired.

#### Note

If i removed the string array from my jquery and from my web service, the web service works perfectly so 100% the problem from the string array

#### am i passing the array correctly?

#### web service

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
        public void LoadService2Daily(string fromDate, string toDate, string[] campaigns)
        {
```

Please help me I really don't know what to do

Comment: Have you tried JSON.stringify for the array?

Comment: @VahidND no how to do that please? and will I change my method to work with your new format?

Comment: Just change the array assignment this way: `campaigns: JSON.stringify(selectedCampaigns)`, and let me know if it helps.